# Cannot verify signature using C-style function calls

Tags: c++, crypto++, ecdsa

The following prints FAIL and I cannot understand why:

```
#include <cryptopp/eccrypto.h>
#include <cryptopp/oids.h>
#include <cryptopp/osrng.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace CryptoPP;
int main() {
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
    ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::PrivateKey private_key;
    ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::PublicKey public_key;
    private_key.Initialize( prng, ASN1::secp160r1() );
    private_key.MakePublicKey(public_key);
    ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Signer signer(private_key);
    ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Verifier verifier(public_key);
    signer.AccessKey().Initialize(prng, ASN1::secp160r1());
    string signature(signer.MaxSignatureLength(), 0);
    string message = "asdf";
    auto signature_length = signer.SignMessage(
        prng, (const byte*)message.data(),
        message.size(), (byte*)signature.data());
    signature.resize(signature_length);
    bool verified = verifier.VerifyMessage(
        (const byte*)message.data(), message.size(),
        (const byte*)signature.data(), signature.size());
    if (verified)
        cout << "PASS" << endl;
    else
        cout << "FAIL" << endl;
}
```

It follows the instructions in crypto++ wiki: https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ECDSA#Message_Signing and verifies with a public key derived from the private used to sign the same message. Should I switch to filters?

Comment: Please modify your source code to create more definitive error messages and then update your posting with the modified source and the error messages.

Comment: How do you suggest I do that? VerifyMessage returns bool so I can't really say how much the verification failed.

Comment: I don't know this package you are using so I can not give you any advice on getting more specific error information. However as you can see, others are also of the opinion that your posting lacks the information needed for anyone to be helpful. Most packages have some mechanism for obtaining additional information in the event of a failure. `errno` is a classic example as well as `GetLastError()`.

Comment: Failure to verify a cryptographic signature is not a sign of an error in (using) the software, if the signature was indeed not created by the same key (pair), hence the lack of an error message for this function. Whether the function and the setup for using it is actually correct is what I'm asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The following prints FAIL and I cannot understand why:

You are close. Looking at the wiki page there are a few problems. First, this is undefined behavior (it has been fixed on the wiki):

```
auto signature_length = signer.SignMessage(
    prng, (const byte*)message.data(),
    message.size(), (byte*)signature.data());
```

To get the non-const pointer you need this instead (but it is not the cause of your issue):

```
auto signature_length = signer.SignMessage(
    prng, (const byte*)&message[0],
    message.size(), (byte*)&signature[0]);
```

Second, when you call `Initialize` twice you whack the old configuration. "Whack" means you generate new parameters. Effectively you overwrote the other private key:

```
private_key.Initialize( prng, ASN1::secp160r1() );
...
signer.AccessKey().Initialize(prng, ASN1::secp160r1());
```

It is not readily apparent, but the `Initialize` that takes a `prng` generates a new key. You want an `Initialize` that *does not* take a `prng`:

```
private_key.Initialize( prng, ASN1::secp160r1() );
...
signer.AccessKey().Initialize(private_key);
```

Third, the page is not clear how to move between Signers/Verifiers and PublicKey/PrivateKey. Here are some other ways to do it for illustration purposes:

```
cryptopp $ cat test.cxx
#include "eccrypto.h"
#include "oids.h"
#include "osrng.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

    ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Signer signer;
    ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Verifier verifier;

    signer.AccessKey().Initialize(prng, ASN1::secp160r1());
    signer.AccessKey().MakePublicKey(verifier.AccessKey());

    std::string signature(signer.MaxSignatureLength(), 0);
    std::string message = "asdf";

    auto signature_length = signer.SignMessage(
        prng, (const byte*)&message[0],
        message.size(), (byte*)&signature[0]);
    signature.resize(signature_length);

    bool verified = verifier.VerifyMessage(
        (const byte*)&message[0], message.size(),
        (const byte*)&signature[0], signature.size());

    if (verified)
        std::cout << "PASS" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "FAIL" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm working from Crypto++ directory so the includes and command line are a little different:

```
cryptopp$ g++ -I . test.cxx ./libcryptopp.a -o test.exe
cryptopp$ ./test.exe
PASS
```

---

If you want to use both Signers/Verifiers and PublicKey/PrivateKey then try something like:

```
cryptopp$ cat test.cxx
#include "eccrypto.h"
#include "oids.h"
#include "osrng.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

    ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Signer signer;
    ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Verifier verifier;

    ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::PrivateKey& sKey = signer.AccessKey();
    sKey.Initialize(prng, ASN1::secp160r1());
    ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::PublicKey& pKey = verifier.AccessKey();
    sKey.MakePublicKey(pKey);

    std::string signature(signer.MaxSignatureLength(), 0);
    std::string message = "asdf";

    auto signature_length = signer.SignMessage(
        prng, (const byte*)&message[0],
        message.size(), (byte*)&signature[0]);
    signature.resize(signature_length);

    bool verified = verifier.VerifyMessage(
        (const byte*)&message[0], message.size(),
        (const byte*)&signature[0], signature.size());

    if (verified)
        std::cout << "PASS" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "FAIL" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

This looks a little unusual:

```
ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Signer signer;
...
signer.AccessKey().Initialize(prng, ASN1::secp160r1());
```

Typically you use `{secp160r1, SHA1}` or `{secp256k1, SHA256}`. That maintains the [Security Levels](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Security_Level) of the system as a whole. When you use `{secp160r1, SHA256}` you are reducing the security level to about 80-bits because of `secp160r1`.

Comment: Thanks for a comprehensive answer and a security tip. Looks like C++17 allows also non-const data() access so it wouldn't be undefined behavior anymore: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data